# Initialize Realm object without data in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

So suppose I have a Dog object that contains a reference to a Toy object:

```
class Dog: Object {

  dynamic var toy: Toy!

  convenience init(toyId: String) {
    self.init()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    toy = realm.object(ofType: Toy.self, forPrimaryKey: toyId)
  }
}
```

In this example, suppose I have a bunch of toys that have already been created in Realm, and I want to create a new instance of a dog and all I have is the toy id (not the actual toy object).

In the example above, I can make this work by doing a lookup for the toy, but if I'm creating a bunch of dogs all at once, this seems inefficient.

The other option, I suppose, is to fetch all the toys upfront and then pass the actual toy object to the dog initializer.

My question is, if I'm just trying to create a new dog, and link it to an existing toy, can that be done without having to fetch the toy?

I'm new to Realm, but when I was using Parse in the past they had a special initializer for this kind of scenario:

```
PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: <String>, objectId: <String?>)
```

The idea was you could reference an object from the primary key, and only fetch the data if you end up needing it. Something like that, it seems, would be ideal for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if I'm just trying to create a new dog, and link it to an existing toy, can that be done without having to fetch the toy?

It is necessary to fetch the toy to establish the relationship between it and the dog.

It's worth noting that looking up an object by primary key does not result in any properties of that object being loaded into memory. The returned object is just a pointer to a specific object in the Realm file on disk. The object's properties are read into memory only when they're accessed.

Comment: Oh interesting! So if I was creating, say, 100 dogs, would it be reasonable to do a object lookup by primary key for each instance (as in my example)? From what you said, it sounds like it might even be more efficient then fetching all the toys upfront. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fetching all the toys up front" or how that would differ from fetching them by primary key, so it's hard to say which would be more efficient.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by that is doing a query for all toys — realm.objects(Toy.self) — and then, say, converting the Result into a standard Dictionary (where the key is the toy id). Assuming there are only 100 possible toys, this would mean loading all of them into memory, but offering a quick means of referencing a toy object when creating however many dog objects (let's say 100 dogs). Does that make sense? I originally thought that would be the right way to do it, but now you've got me thinking I should just look up the toys by primary key as it's much faster than I first thought.

Comment: I doubt there'd be a significant performance difference between the two approaches. There are slight trade-offs either way but I'd expect the performance of this specific operation to be outweighed by other work you end up doing at the same time.

Comment: Got it — thanks again for your help! It's been a few days now, and I'm nearly done refactoring my code to use Realm. I'm really happy with it so far! :)